# Why is the Teen Titans theme song sung with an accent?

Tags: comics, dc, teen-titans

The theme in question is here:

.

I am Asian and when I listen to this song it sounds like it's sung by Asian people, more specifically maybe Chinese. What I mean is when "Teen Titans" is sung, it just sounds like it's accented.

There is nothing wrong with it but why was it made this way?

Comment: I have nothing to back this up as fact, but I always heard it more as a Japanese accent - likely a nod to the anime influences to the artistic style.

Comment: I hate to be a stickler, but I just entered "teen titans theme song" on Google and all the info came first thing up. Why would you assume it was "accented" without so much as trying to check it?

Comment: @MishaRosnach I didn't assume it was accented, when I hear the song, it sounds like it's accented. I googled "teen titan theme song accented" and nothing in the list caught my attention. Don't assume I didn't do research

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The theme song for Teen Titans was recorded by [Puffy AmiYumi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffy_AmiYumi), a Japanese pop duo.

[image: Puffy AmiYumi]

Comment: No wonder, thanks

Comment: Titans in Japan had the theme completely in Japanese iirc

Comment: @cde Actually, the [theme song is switched from episode to episode](http://teentitans.wikia.com/wiki/Teen_Titans_Theme_Song).

Comment: Can we just take a moment to revel in the fact that the answer was "Because it's sung by Puffy AmiUmi".  That is so perfect.